# Exclude fields for Django model, only on creation

Tags: django, forms, model

I am building a notification system for a company, where admin users can create Projects and add users to them. The Project model has 9 attributes but I only want to show 3 or 4 fields when a Project is created, but show them all when an existing Project is updated.

This change will only need to be reflected on the Django admin site, so I have extended the ProjectAdmin with my own ProjectForm, where I extend the **init** method to check if it is a new instance and if so remove certain fields.

```
# models.py
class Project(models.Model):
    project_number = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    permit = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser, blank=True, related_name='project_users')
    # add a default

    levels = models.ManyToManyField('Level', blank=True, related_name='project_levels')

    total_contract_hours = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, verbose_name='Total Design Hours')
    hours_used = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, verbose_name='Total Design Hours Used')

    notes = models.ManyToManyField('notes.ProjectNote', related_name='core_project_notes', blank=True)

    history = HistoricalRecords()

    def __str__(self):
        ret_str = "{} {}".format(self.project_number, self.name)
        if self.permit:
            ret_str += "  |  Permit: {}".format(self.permit)
        return ret_str



# admin.py
class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProjectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        attrs = {'class': 'form-control', 'required': True}
        if self.instance and self.instance.pk is None:
            # creating project

            exclude = ['is_active', 'users', 'levels', 'hours_used', 'notes']
            for field in exclude:
                try:
                    del self.fields[field]
                except ValueError:
                    print('{} does not exist'.format(field))

        for field in self.fields.values():
            field.widget.attrs = attrs

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['project_number', 'name', 'total_contract_hours']


class ProjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ProjectForm
    fields = ['project_number', 'name', 'permit', 'is_active', 'users', 'levels', 'total_contract_hours', 'hours_used', 'notes']
```

As I stated I only want basic Project fields on creation, but show all attributed when updating existing Project. With just these changes, I now get a KeyError:

KeyError: "Key 'is_active' not found in 'ProjectForm'. Choices are: 
  name, permit, project_number, total_contract_hours."

However, when I print the available fields it returns an OrderedDict with all of the model attributes as keys. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Your logic seems wrong. Perhaps you mean `if not self.instance or self.instance.pk is None:`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately, that did not fix the problem. The fields that it currently says are the only available attributes were 4 fields that I had previously added to the exclude variable, however, this affected both creation and updating so I am trying to address that issue but I keep getting that KeyError. Could it have to do with how Django caches objects?

Comment: When you instantiate the form with super(ProjectForm) will that instantiate a Project object or is instance not fully instantiated at the point you are creating the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, the field must be in listed in Meta and then you just set the field to be a hidden field.

class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ProjectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    print("Adding project")

    if not self.instance or self.instance.pk is None:
        for name, field in self.fields.items():
            if name in ['design_manager', ]:
                field.widget = forms.HiddenInput()

class Meta:
    model = Project
    fields = ['project_number', 'name', 'design_manager', 'total_contract_hours']
```

class ProjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ProjectForm

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    obj.design_manager = request.user
    super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```